best way to plug unused screw holes in wood deck
my redwood 2x6 decking was originally screwed in from the top. the wood is in pretty decent shape, so i’m going to:

remove the planks
put joist tape on the joists
flip the planks over
use hidden screws (camo type) to screw down the planks

i’ll be left with a lot of little unused screw holes that i’d like to patch. i could use bondo or wood filler type of material or wood plugs. i’m looking for suggestions on the best way to do this. i’m going to use an opaque stain, so i’m not concerned about the color used to plug the holes. thx

The "best" way is relative. I think all those options will work for you. This is going to be pretty labor-intensive regardless of how you choose to do it.

The classy but time consuming method is tapered plugs, either purchased or made by you with a drill press. The low rent version is dowels, cut flush. If you go bondo, test your stain with it — it might not look nice.

Why not simply put dummy screws through the unused holes?  They can be shorter (i.e. cheaper) since they're nonstructural.

i don’t mind the tediousness of this job so that’s not my main criteria. my main concern is the longevity, and secondary is the level of difficulty. i don’t want to see the top screws, plus they promote rot if they are the slightest bit indented, so that’s why i’m going with hidden diagonal screws. i like the tapered dowel idea with a plug cutter, but i’m not sure how to taper them. would that be with sand paper chucked into a drill?

As you state, dowels would be longest-lasting and least likely to form dimples holding water. Tapering is not important, if the dowel closely matches the hole size -- a few taps with a hammer can set it. ("Percussive maintenance," usually applied to uncooperative mechanism)
